# ec2_metadata fact not updating

Tags: puppet, openstack, facter

I have added a "role" value to my instance metadata (I'm running on Openstack).

I see it in `curl http://169.254.169.254/openstack/latest/meta_data.json`, but it is not appearing in the ec2_metadata fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussion with @garethr (and checking [this documentation](https://github.com/puppetlabs/facter/blob/stable/lib/facter/ec2/rest.rb)) it turns out that facter does not see those parts of the metadata tree.